# Does NSURLSession support FTP upload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I want to upload files to an FTP. I would like to use `NSURLSession` for its backgrounding support. Apple documentation says it is supported but so far I have been unable to find it. The POC I have done is as follows:

The sample code from apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) uses NSStreams which I would like to avoid.
On the other hand Apple's URL programming guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) says:

The URL loading system provides support for accessing resources using the following protocols:

- File Transfer Protocol (ftp://)
- Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http://)
- Hypertext Transfer Protocol with encryption (https://)
- Local file URLs (file:///)
- Data URLs (data://)

So far I have searched through `NSURLSessionUploadTask` and `NSURLSessionDataTask` but I have only been able to find HTTP protocols, which will not work for FTP.

Much appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the [NSURLSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1)

*The NSURLSession class and related classes provide an API for downloading content via HTTP.*

You can use other library with [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/conceptual/cfnetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) Framework like [WhiteRaccon](https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon) to upload file to FTP server.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/CookiesandCustomProtocols/CookiesandCustomProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH10-SW3 again it says that `URL loading system natively supports the http, https, file, ftp, and data protocols. Implement a custom protocol by subclassing NSURLProtocol  then registering the with the URL loading system using the NSURLProtocol class method registerClass:.When an NSURLSession,NSURLConnection,or NSURLDownload object initiates a connection for an NSURLRequest object` also http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/

Comment: Also dont want to use CFNetwork if NSURLSession can handle it because of the backgrounding support for NSURLSession in iOS 7